# Can't load WCF Service in Silverlight project

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I'm using Visual studio Ultimat 2013, ve got a serious problem whene I tried to load WCF service in my Silverlight project, it show me this error sorry it's in french means that he can't load service.

![enter image description here][1]
hear my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
  Pour plus d'informations sur la configuration de votre application ASP.NET, consultez
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="ServiceWebProject.Web.Servicecom.customBinding0">
                    <binaryMessageEncoding />
                    <httpTransport />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service name="ServiceWebProject.Web.Servicecom">
                <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceWebProject.Web.Servicecom.customBinding0"
                    contract="ServiceWebProject.Web.Servicecom" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
            multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Hope that you  can help me.

Answer (score 0):

The message written in comment part is not an error it just says "for more info about the configuration of your app consult the URL".. 
I think if there is any problem generating the proxy file of your service you should check out the results in output window and report the real error..